# Можно ли разрабатывать на Android без IDE?

Tags: android

Возможно ли создание легковесных и шустрых программ на Android без Eclipse, Android SDK и т.п.?

Например, при необходимости написать программу на самом телефоне.

**UPD**: на Хабре появилась неплохая [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/339938/) об оптимизации размера APK.

Comment: Eclipse - это среда разработки. вместо неё можно хоть в блокноте писать
Android SDK - инструменты, чтобы ваше приложение создалось. без него никак
Писать на самом телефоне? Вы явно любитель БДСМ и тому подобного

Comment: Для Андроида тоже есть IDE, см. AIDE в маркете.

Comment: Чисто теоретически можно построить дом используя один лобзик. Только зачем!?

Comment: @Sviat Volkov Спасибо за прояснение. Не обязательно на телефоне, хоть бы и на ПК. Лишь бы программа была малого размера.

Comment: Сам вопрос сводится к следующему: можно ли создавать приложения на Android, используя только саму ОС, блокнот и компилятор.

Comment: Использование какой бы то ни было IDE никаким образом не повлияет на увеличение размера получившейся программы, либо ее "шустрость", зато отказ от использования IDE изрядно добавит геморроя. IDE  - это только инструмент, продвинутый редактор текста с интегрированным сборщиком проекта и дебаггером, "от себя" никакая IDE не добавляет ни чего либо увеличивающего размер программы ни уменьшающего ее "шустрость". Если у вас с этими параметрами проблемы - эти проблемы в **вашем коде**, а не в среде разроботки. Отказ от IDE только усугубит такие проблемы, а не решит их.

Comment: Для создания программы на android непременно понадобится: Блокнот, какая-то система сборки, Android SDK, Java JDK

Comment: @pavloff Спасибо. Пожалуй, в этом случае исключить надо не IDE, а всякие конструкторы макетов с большим объёмом лишнего кода.

Comment: Да, это верное направление мысли - оптимизация кода и ресурсов. Так же если вам нужно легкое и шустрое приложение имеет смысл отказаться от многих библиотек поддержки (в основном именно они сильно влияют на размер, особенно AppCompat) и установить минимальный SDK  проекта куда-то к API 15. Пять лет назад тоже писали приложения, а современное API сильно обросло "жиром". Конечно ваше приложение не будет иметь чудесного Материл дизайна и няшных анимаций, но и занимать будет в два раза меньше места, а "шевелиться" в два раза шустрее

Comment: @pavlofff Если посредством Android SDK можно работать только с API Android, то мне этого достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно. Если брать среду ПК/консоль, то есть специальные фанаты этого дела, которые редактируют тексты на vi/emacs/sublime и собирают через gradle.

Вообще в этом есть определенный фан (в работе без IDE) - мозги тренирует на раз.

Если говорить серьезно, то связка [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com) + gradle это наиболее жизнеспособная связка, которая почти может сравниться с полноценным IDE.